# compile sample.java and jgraph_5.8.3.1.jar

Tags: java

In my java application I need to compile my own java file and jgraph.jar file simultaneously ...how can I Compile both file at the same time in command prompt....?

Comment: Aren't `jar` files already compiled (and zip'd)? (And isn't this the kind of question you better ask google, as it's faster and doesn't consume prople's time needlessly?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try following:

```
c:\ javac -cp "x;y" MyClass.java
```

where x= path_to_folder_That_contain_your_java_file 
and y=path_to_jar

Example:-  If your java file resides under c:\JD foler and your jar file is under c:\Jar then do as follows:

```
c:\ javac -cp "c:\JD;C:\jar\jgrapgh.jar" MyClass.java
```

**Edit:-**

If you have package statement in your class then give folder path upto start of that package. For example if you have "example" package and it resides under C:\ than try this:

```
C:\> javac -cp "c:\;c:\example\jgraph.jar" first.java
```

Hope this helps. For any other help feel free to comment on this answer.

Comment: c:\example> javac -cp "c:\example\;c:\example\jgraph_5.8.3.1.jar" first.java       .....both files are stored in c:\example directory....

Comment: What problem do you face now? Will you please elaborate.

Comment: What ever objects i create of the class which are in .jar file.only for those objects error generates that "cannot find symbol".....

Comment: If you wanna say that you are not able to access class files from jar. Then you should check for syntax, name of the jar file in command line. Make sure jar files contains that class which you are trying to access. You have imported the appropriate class in your Java file. Because i had tried it on my machine and it works fine.                        Let me know error comes at compile time or run time?

Comment: okay..for that I first of all I have to confirm that classes are exists in .jar file...Let Me Confirm......You helped me very well...for that Thank You Very Much...

Comment: hey, let me know the output of checking? Your problem solved or not?

Comment: Yes, it has been solved.....I have put those files in source code of java where i have installed java...in c:\program files\java